# how do you unistall alamofire?

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, alamofire

I created a copy of my xcode project with a different name. I now want to remove alamorefire together with the pods generated related to it so that i can do a fresh install of the alamorefire framework.

Comment: So you want to update the version of alamofire?

Answer (score 1):

First comment your library in your Podfile like below:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    #pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

at terminal run this command:

```
pod install
```

this will remove library from your project. And after that open commented line:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

and after that re-run install command:

```
pod install
```

library will re-installed in your project.